# Angularjs $http does not call the api in GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to call an API using $http.get method but its not calling that API instead just returning 404 error.

My $http

```js
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine'
}).then(function(res) {
  debugger
  console.log(res.data);
}, function(header) {
  debugger
  console.log("HTTP Head: " + JSON.stringify(header));
});
```

```html
//My route public class SalesManagementAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration { public override string AreaName { get { return "SalesManagement"; } } public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) { context.MapRoute( "SalesManagement_default",
"SalesManagement/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); } }
```

My API:

```
public class SecuredSalesAPI : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetProductLine()
    {
        var sp = entity.spGetProductPerformance(startDate, end, "HPL");
        return Json(sp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

// and the namespace is 
// namespace WebApp.Areas.SalesManagement.Controllers
```

Comment: `method: 'POST',` | `trying to call an API using $http.get` <= Your code conflicts with your statement, which is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: If you are not user what your route url is then test it directly from the browser first, this works great with http GET. If using a non GET end point test with Fiddler or PostMan. If you are still not sure what the end point actually is then install [NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/), this will create a help area in your site with a page that lists all your available web api end points including parameters, their types, and the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method to 'GET' instead of 'POST'

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine'
        }).then(function (res) {

            console.log(res.data);
        }, function (header) {

            console.log("HTTP Head: " + JSON.stringify(header));
        });
```

Also add keyword controller to your controller class name. ie; 
public class SecuredSalesAPIController : Controller
{
}
and call the service from client side as before.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to get but you defined method as post.

`$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine'
}).then(function (res) {
  debugger
  console.log(res.data);
}, function (header) {
  debugger
  console.log("HTTP Head: " + JSON.stringify(header));
});`

Comment: Check your route config inside area and check how route is defined

Comment: just updated my AreaRegistration. All other API and $http in other files are working but not this

Comment: can u try using $http.get('/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine').then(function(response){
});

Also the controller name should follow word controller. But its missing in your controller name. not in the url,,  but in the classname

Comment: public class SecuredSalesAPIController : Controller. Add the keyword controller in the class name. Hope it will fix the issue. and call the api like before.
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine'
        }).then(function (res) {

Comment: **Issac Johnson**, SecuredSalesAPIController : Controller worked great. thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

API only pass data by url.you have to use GET method to get data.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/SalesManagement/SecuredSalesAPI/GetProductLine'
}).then(function(res) {

    debugger
    console.log(res.data);

}, function(header) {

    debugger
    console.log("HTTP Head: " + JSON.stringify(header));

});
```